# How to uploads files from android app to node js Server?

Tags: android, node.js

I am making an University project, an android app that connects with a server, in this case i am using node js, but it may be any of them, apache, and my app uploads an image jpg (I want to change this on the side server in order to receive any type of image) to a folder in node js, So i run the server by console, It works fine, but when i push the button (upload image)in the app android that sends the pic, my console shows post /uploads, good, but doesn't receives the pic file in the folder uploads, my server code here:

/////////////////////////////////////////////app.js////////////////////////////////////////

```
/**
/*Module dependencies.
*/
var express  = require('express');
var connect = require('connect');
var app      = express();
var port     = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// Configuration
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(connect.cookieParser());
app.use(connect.logger('dev'));
app.use(connect.bodyParser());

app.use(connect.json());   
app.use(connect.urlencoded());

// Routes

require('./routes/routes.js')(app);


app.listen(port);
console.log('The App runs on port ' + port);
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////routes.js//////////////////////////////////

```
var fs = require('fs');


module.exports = function(app) {


app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.end("Node-File-Upload");

});
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
console.log(req.files.image.originalFilename);
console.log(req.files.image.path);
    fs.readFile(req.files.image.path, function (err, data){
    var dirname = "C:\\node\\Node-File-Upload\\file-upload";
    var newPath = dirname + "\\uploads\\" +     req.files.image.originalFilename;
    fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
    if(err){
    res.json({'response':"Error"});
    }else {
    res.json({'response':"Saved"});       
}
});
});
});


app.get('/uploads/:file', function (req, res){
    file = req.params.file;
    var dirname = "C:\\node\\Node-File-Upload\\file-upload";
    var img = fs.readFileSync(dirname + "\\uploads\\" + file);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpg' });
    res.end(img, 'binary');

});
};
```

I think the probem is the way i am typing the windows directory with "\"

Comment: Just a heads up: if this is a public app, you should ensure that `path.resolve(newPath).indexOf('C:\\node\\Node-File-Upload\\file-upload\\uploads') === 0` before calling `fs.writeFile()` because someone could maliciously send a file with a filename like `..\\..\\..\\..\\Windows\\calc.exe` (similarly with your `fs.readFileSync()` usage. Also, to move a file you can use [`fs.rename()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback) instead of reading the whole file in memory just to write it back out again.

Comment: ok, I am gettin this from console post /uploads 404, and from browser get /uploads 404

Comment: Your `POST` route that you currently have defined is `/upload` not `/uploads`.

Answer (score 0):

i saw your question and i think that you should do it like this because that's the way i solved the problem and i hope that it will help you.
and if you want android code ask me i will it too!

```
    app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
        if (req.url == '/upload' && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      res.send('Done!');
    });
    form.on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
        var percent_complete = (bytesReceived / bytesExpected) * 100;
        console.log(percent_complete.toFixed(2));
    });

    form.on('error', function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });

    form.on('end', function(fields, files) {
        /* Temporary location of our uploaded file */
        var temp_path = this.openedFiles[0].path;
        /* The file name of the uploaded file */
        var file_name = this.openedFiles[0].name;
        /* Location where we want to copy the uploaded file */
        var new_location = 'public/images/uploads/chat/';

        fs.copy(temp_path, new_location + file_name, function(err) {  
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                console.log("your file folder after copy " + new_location);
                fs.rename(new_location+file_name, new_location+file_name, function (err) {
           if(!err){
                console.log('file renamed ! '+new_location+file_name, new_location+file_name);
           }else{
            console.log(err);
           }
            });
                fs.unlink(temp_path, function(err){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err)
                    }else{
                    console.log(temp_path+' file has been deleted from temp folder!');
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });

    return;
  }});
```